# CSS3 animation stutters/jumps after being paused

Tags: css, css-animations

My CSS animation declares an `animation-play-state: paused` on `div:hover`.  Problem is (atleast in Chrome), the animation stutters/jumps when hovering off the element.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AHqLE/

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and played a bit with it. For me everything runs smoothly. I am on kubuntu with chromium 25.0.1364.160, JavaScript V8 3.15.11.16

Comment: yes I am also having this same issue — it appears to quickly jump back to it's default state then proceed to pick up the animation where it left off

Comment: It's a known bug, I think — seeing the same on Chrome 30.0.1599.69, where the initiate state flashes before the animation resuming. You're not alone!

Comment: I was able to reproduce this as well using chrome.

Comment: I can reproduce this also in chrome, even tried different units instead of px, still happens.

Comment: i'm on chrome (31.0.1650.63 m) and works like a charm (and it's pretty cool too)

Comment: same ver. as Yenn, @pruett what SO an chrome version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this **now works** in the latest Chrome version (Version 31.0.1650.63)

An additional note to this issue: I believe I solved it (at the time) by using `top/bottom` values as opposed to `translateY` values

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` or `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to force hardware acceleration. I add this to any transition or animation I use so that Chrome doesn't leave trails.